# Does Mysql driver in itself implements DataSource interface?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

The JDBC documentation from Oracle says that driver provider should implement DataSource interface, but in real project source file, I always see the DataSource come from 3rd, such as DBCP connection pool.

I wonder if MySQL driver in itself implements DataSource interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about [Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/), it provides:

- `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource` (which implements [DataSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html)),
- `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource` (which implements [ConnectionPoolDataSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/CommonDataSource.html))
- `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource` (which implements [XADataSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/XADataSource.html))

So, as far as your question goes. **Yes** *Connector/J* provides implementations to the `DataSource` interface and conforms with JDBC specs.

But, as you are aware by your question and @Piotr's answer, most applications will never deal with those implementations directly. At least in ten years as a Java Developer I have never done that. Let the Java EE App Server handle connections for you, or install a third party connection pool if you are down to standalone applications.

Comment: so, in its option package, I see! thank you. Of cause, I will use 3rd connection pool! I just want to know it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use native DataSource provided by JDBC driver, but what you usually do is you use a connection pool like DBCP, C3P0 or BoneCP.

Comment: " native DataSource provided by JDBC driver" what's the native, I mean the class name inside mysql driver?

Comment: `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource` or `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource` see [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)